# ng-checked checkbox

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el sgte codigo:

```
<input
    type="checkbox" ng-checked="false"
    ng-model="query"
    ng-checked="loadValues(column.field)" />
```

Cada vez que le doy al checkbox llama al método, pero yo solo quiero que llame cuando este en check = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo en el ng-change en vez de usar el chequed:

```
ng-change="((query)?loadValues(column.field):'')"
```

Podrías también verificar en la función dentro del controlador, si es verdadero el valor y continúas con la ejecución:

```
loadValues(value){
  if(query){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Te dejo un plunker funcionando con el primer ejemplo: http://plnkr.co/edit/oB7rx8tID2orly9NfKQI?p=preview

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando, en caso contrario, no dudes en volver a preguntar. Saludos